# Python selenium chromedriver gives me errors after a while

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running a python code using selenium.

By design the browser is opened on start and waits until a message is detected at a website (this part is done by bs4)

However, I found the chromedriver reporting a dozen of the following error message after a few hours.

[18396:13428:0210/134259.339:ERROR:entry_impl.cc<1080>] No file for 800000e

Is there a way to avoid this message or if this is inevitable, restart the browser if this error is detected?

Comment: Update the question with the complete error trace log.

Comment: I accidently closed the chromedriver window...